# Does MySQL Profiler use cache of queries?

Tags: mysql, caching, profiler

I wonder if the cache is used in the embedded MySQL Profiler. For example, if I run a query:

```
mysql> select count(*) from comment;
```

and after that I run the following queries:

```
mysql> set profiling=1;
mysql> select count(*) from comment;
mysql> show profiles;
```

Does profiler use cache in that case?
Empirically it seems that the cache is not being used. But I want to know for sure.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example [here](https://pantheon.io/blog/profiling-mysql-queries-better-performance) that shows profilter output, and two of the steps shown in the result are:

```
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000004 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000151 |
```

This suggests that it does use the query cache. Other sites that demonstrate how to profile queries include turning off the query cache.